# Finding records that exist in one table but not another (matching) table with no primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking at changing a data load that is done using an external tool to generate a flat files based on several joins using that tool, and then loaded into a table using SQL*Loader.

I'd like to move away from using this program and use external tables, moving the table insert into the database instead. I'm uncertain about the validity of my joins versus what the program was doing though. When I compare what I have made using external tables, I have 14702052 total records and 14268891 distinct records. When I compare to the table loaded with the old tool with the same data I have 14669198 records, with 14268888 distinct. I'm not worried about the total number as duplicates are ok for this, it's updating some values and a duplicate should not matter.

I can't seem to figure out what the extra distinct values are though. I've tried minus, not in, not exists, and joining, maybe a few other tries I don't remember off the top of my head, but I get no records. There is no primary key for the table either to join on either which makes checking hard.

If it were less records I could compare using Kdiff3, but as it stands the output is way too large to run on my computer. I may try to break it down by rownum as a worst case attempt to find the extra records.

Anyone have any suggestions on an alternative?

Edit:
Here's the table structure, had to strip out some of the names

```
CREATE TABLE T ( 
ID varchar2(11 byte), 
CLASS_CD varchar2(4 byte), 
ITEM_NAME varchar2(60 byte), 
UNIT_OF_ISSUE varchar2(2 byte), 
PRICE number(15,2), 
ITEM_CD varchar2(3 byte), 
SERVICE_CD varchar2(2 byte));
```

Here's a sample record, though I've replaced most of the values for sensitivity.

```
ID         CLASS_CD ITEM_NAME      UOI     PRICE   ITEM_CD   SERVICE_CD
000000057  1111     NAME       FT      5.91    NULL      BC
```

Comment: sample data & desired output

Comment: Added the table structure and example record. I don't really care about how the output looks, just trying to find out what those 3 additional records are that show up on my distinct count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have both new and old table in the same structure, this should have given you at least 3 records

```
select * from new_table
minus 
select * from old_table
```

In any case, use this query to find the differences

```
select      count(case when tab='O' then 1 end) as cnt_old
           ,count(case when tab='N' then 1 end) as cnt_new

           ,id,class_cd,item_name,uoi,price,item_cd,service_cd

from        (           select 'O' as tab,t.* from old_table t
            union all   select 'N'       ,t.* from new_table t
            ) t

group by    id,class_cd,item_name,uoi,price,item_cd,service_cd   

having      count(case when tab='O' then 1 end) = 0
        or  count(case when tab='N' then 1 end) = 0
;
```

Comment: This is the optimal solution; for some reason on SO it is often overlooked.

Comment: I'll have to take that down for the future, thanks! Still learning a lot in this role.
Unfortunately neither not working, which likely means something else is wrong with my data. Kdiff3 with sections might be a good check for me still. I'll mark this the answer as it does look to do what I needed though! I guess minus I skipped after I got results greater than the supposed difference, for some reason in my head I thought I had 0 results from it before.

Comment: Just wanted to add it was a problem with the data, was a carriage return that was messing with my flat file. Once that was cleared up both above queries worked.

Comment: Great :-) P.s. the function `DUMP` saved me numerous times.